# I co-signed a car but I am listed as the primary account holder for the loan

Tags: united-states, refinance, auto-loan, co-sign

I co-signed a car and want to be removed. My first thing is that I am listed as the primary account holder for the loan, but I signed the papers as the co-signer/co-buyer. If to fix the situation as being the primary account holder means refinancing needs to be done, what can the primary buyer do to be refinanced if she needed my credit score in able to get the car.  Also, what can I do if she is not able to be refinanced?

Comment: What country are you from? In many places there's no distinction between primary and co-signer other than whose name is the first on the bill.

Comment: @littleadv South Carolina

Answer (score 3):

First of all you do not "co-sign a car". I assume what you mean by this is that you co-signed a loan, and the money was used to buy a car. Once you signed that loan YOU OWED THE MONEY.

Once a loan exists, it exists, and you will owe the money until the loan is paid. If you do not want to owe the money, then you need to pay back the money you borrowed. You may not think "you" borrowed the money because the car went to someone else. THE BANK AND THE COURTS DO NOT CARE. All they care about is that YOU signed the loan, so as far as they are concerned YOU owe the money and you owe ALL of the money to the bank, and the only way to change that is to pay the money back.

Answer (score 2):

The buyer can get another cosigner or you can sell the car to pay off the loan. These are your only options if financing cannot be obtained independently.

Comment: would she be able to refinance without another cosigner?

Comment: Presumably you as the cosigner have ensured that payments were all made on time. It's possible that the credit score has increased enough to get financing on the same terms. The more likely scenario if there is no cosigner would be a higher interest rate. Trading for a cheaper car might mitigate some of the problem. I can't make any predictions without a lot more information about the buyer's income, credit score, the actual car in question, and the outstanding balance on the loan.

Comment: So if she cannot refinance there is nothing i can do about being the primary account holder on the loan even though i am not the primary buyer of the car

Comment: As I said before, you have some undesirable options, but as an account holder that gives you leverage to get the loan refinanced, even at a higher interest rate.

Comment: There really is no important difference between the primary buyer and co-signer, you are both equally liable for the payments.

Comment: Could it be consolidated? And if so could I then be removed if she was the one to have it done?

Comment: @Alexis usually the way to remove yourself from the loan is through refinance.

Comment: @littleadv Is there usually a time frame I have to wait until I can refinance or could it be done at any time?

Comment: @Alexis the sooner the better since cars lose value very fast.

Comment: @littleadv thank you so much for the info.. i was just in a car wreck this morning so that may have to wait just a little while. But again, thanks!

Comment: @Alexis hope you're ok...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot be *removed* from a loan. The car buyer must obtain a *new* loan (without your cosignature) and use the proceeds to pay off this one. If the buyer cannot get a new loan, then you're stuck.